# How Do I read CloudKit Errors?

Tags: php, json, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I have a php script that's trying to create a record in a CloudKit database.

It returns this error:

> object(stdClass)#1 (3) {   ["uuid"]=>   string(36)
>   "c70072a1-fab6-491b-a68f-03b9056223e1"   ["serverErrorCode"]=>
>   string(11) "BAD_REQUEST"   ["reason"]=>   string(62)
>   "BadRequestException: Unexpected input at [line: 2, column: 10]" }

I presume this tells me exactly what the problem is, but I don't know how to interpret it. Where is line 2 and column 10?

I think its related to the JSON I'm sending in the create record request.

```
$url = 'https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/' . $CONTAINER .    '/development/public/records/modify';
$opDict = '{"operationType": "create",
"record":"Artists",
"fields": {"firstName":{"value":"Mei"}, 
"lastName": {"value":"Chen"}, 
"principalDiscipline": {"value":""},
"secondaryDiscipline":{"value":""}},
"recordName":"Mei Chen"}';

$body = '{"operations":['.$opDict.']}';
echo $body;
```

When I check the output from $body

> {"operations":[{"operationType": "create", "record":"Artists",
>   "fields": {"firstName":{"value":"Mei"}, "lastName": {"value":"Chen"},
>   "principalDiscipline": {"value":""},
>   "secondaryDiscipline":{"value":""}}, "recordName":"Mei Chen"}]}

it passes JSON lint, so I am not sure it is a JSON problem.

Can someone explain to me how to interpret the error I'm getting from CloudKit. The docs are a little vague on errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got absolutely no clue about CloudKit, but I found [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/ModifyRecords/ModifyRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH2-SW5) with the followin example:

```
{
    "operationType" : "create",
    "record" : {
        "recordType" : "Artist",
        "fields" : {
            "firstName" : {"value" : "Mei"},
            "lastName" : {"value" : "Chen"}
        }
        "recordName" : "Mei Chen"
    },
}
```

which definitely differs from what you try to send, both in terms of data structure 
(your `record` is not a dictionary) and content (you have no `recordType`).
So while your JSON is syntactically correct, you are simply sending invalid content data wrapped in valid JSON which is most likely the reason you are seeing the error message.

Comment: Bravo Marcin. I completely missed the absence `"record"` and `"recordType"` and that's the same doc page I was working from!  Works perfectly now. Thanks 1000x. I need more sleep, I think.